# Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because of bad file mode

Tags: linux, logs, logrotate

How can I do logrotate? I can see no effect when I do logrotate:

```
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/etc/logrotate.d# cd ..
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/etc# cd ..
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because of bad file mode.

Handling 0 logs
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/# chmod 644 /etc/logrotate.d/*
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/# cd /etc/logrotate.d
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/etc/logrotate.d# ls
apport       custom   pm-utils  speech-dispatcher    upstart
apt          dpkg     ppp       ufw
cups-daemon  lightdm  rsyslog   unattended-upgrades
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/etc/logrotate.d# cd ..
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/etc# cd ..
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because of bad file mode.

Handling 0 logs
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/# cd /var/log
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# ls -larth
total 34M
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Feb 18  2016 speech-dispatcher
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Mai 19  2016 upstart
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 fsck
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     31 Jul 19  2016 dmesg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    57K Jul 19  2016 bootstrap.log
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 hp
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 14 13:17 apt
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 14 13:20 installer
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 19 09:50 unattended-upgrades
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   3,8K Jun 19 09:55 fontconfig.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    554 Jun 19 15:02 apport.log.1
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 20 07:35 lightdm
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   836K Jun 20 07:35 syslog.1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    32K Jun 20 14:31 faillog
-rw-------  1 root utmp    768 Jul 14 09:28 btmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 14 10:38 dist-upgrade
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    43K Jul 14 10:45 alternatives.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   286K Jul 14 11:04 lastlog
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 18 08:59 sysstat
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   1,8M Jul 18 11:13 dpkg.log
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 18 12:19 cups
-rw-r-----  1 root adm     14K Jul 18 12:20 apport.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    32K Jul 18 18:38 Xorg.0.log.old
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   1,9K Jul 18 18:44 gpu-manager.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1009 Jul 18 18:44 boot.log
drwxrwxr-x 13 root syslog 4,0K Jul 18 18:44 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp    85K Jul 18 18:45 wtmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    29K Jul 18 21:17 Xorg.0.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   5,7M Jul 18 21:18 kern.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   580K Jul 18 21:50 auth.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24M Jul 18 21:54 syslog
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# logrotate -f /etc/logroate.conf
error: cannot stat /etc/logroate.conf: No such file or directory
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# ls -larth
total 34M
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Feb 18  2016 speech-dispatcher
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Mai 19  2016 upstart
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 fsck
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     31 Jul 19  2016 dmesg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    57K Jul 19  2016 bootstrap.log
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 hp
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4,0K Jul 19  2016 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 14 13:17 apt
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 14 13:20 installer
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 19 09:50 unattended-upgrades
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   3,8K Jun 19 09:55 fontconfig.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    554 Jun 19 15:02 apport.log.1
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jun 20 07:35 lightdm
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   836K Jun 20 07:35 syslog.1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    32K Jun 20 14:31 faillog
-rw-------  1 root utmp    768 Jul 14 09:28 btmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 14 10:38 dist-upgrade
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    43K Jul 14 10:45 alternatives.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   286K Jul 14 11:04 lastlog
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 18 08:59 sysstat
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   1,8M Jul 18 11:13 dpkg.log
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4,0K Jul 18 12:19 cups
-rw-r-----  1 root adm     14K Jul 18 12:20 apport.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    32K Jul 18 18:38 Xorg.0.log.old
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   1,9K Jul 18 18:44 gpu-manager.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1009 Jul 18 18:44 boot.log
drwxrwxr-x 13 root syslog 4,0K Jul 18 18:44 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp    85K Jul 18 18:45 wtmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    29K Jul 18 21:17 Xorg.0.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   5,7M Jul 18 21:18 kern.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   580K Jul 18 21:50 auth.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24M Jul 18 21:55 syslog
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log#
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are changing permission on logrotate.d. you need to `chmod 644 /etc/logrotate.conf`
And `chown root:root /etc/logrotate.conf`
And then it could work

Comment: nope , i did it, still no change in var/log sizes

Comment: There same error on run in debug mode? `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: yeah same error... `/var/log# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because of bad file mode.

Handling 0 logs`

Comment: What is output of ` ls -l /etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: `rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 703 Mai  6  2015 /etc/logrotate.conf` is the output

Comment: You have permision: 777, and need to Change them, only root can write this file. Did you have any error on chmod 644 ?

Comment: I am running all these commands as root user by logging into root using `sudo su` .Should i use chown command logging out of root and logging into normal user?

Comment: No, you can do that only as root, I have no idea why its no chmod file to 644

Comment: Ahhh ... okay but i can get a clue from my previous runs though i do not understand the meaning of it `sudo su-
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable` gives me this message and whenever i do sudo when I am using like normal user, it displays this message that it is world writable.

Comment: Ok, one more idea;p do you have write perm to filesystem ( is not mounted as readonly)? Try `chmod -v 644`

Comment: `root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# chmod -v 644 /etc/logrotate.conf 
mode of '/etc/logrotate.conf' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# ls -l /etc/logrotate.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 703 Mai  6  2015 /etc/logrotate.conf` yeah got the permissions.

Comment: You have wrong permission on files in /etc. World writable is mean that group other have write Access ( third digit in chmod, or --- --- rwx on LS -l )

Comment: How can i change the permissions then? should i change it during boot? going to recover mode?

Comment: You need to audit your /etc/ permissions, because there could be problem with other software, you may try to `chmod o-rwx` on files in etc, and lookbook into syslog for errors

Comment: I dont knows about auto methods to reset permision, look [this] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/308939/how-to-reset-default-permissions-for-etc)

Comment: `root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# gksudo chown root:root /etc/
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# gksudo chmod u+x /etc/
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# gksudo chmod a+r /etc/
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# ls -l /etc/logrotate.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 703 Mai  6  2015 /etc/logrotate.conf
root@me-Latitude-E5550:/var/log# ` i think i got permissions as root user.

Comment: ahh i got back my right permissions now... but when i run logrotate command it `
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp      0 Jul 19 15:33 wtmp
-rw-rw----  1 root utmp      0 Jul 19 15:33 btmp
drwxrwxr-x 13 root syslog 4,0K Jul 19 15:33 .` only these are becoming 0 others in /var/log aren't and  Iam running out of system memory now.Can i delete log files manually? This logrotate isnt working

Comment: You can delete logs manuały, i suggest to delete all .gz and with .1 files in /var/log that are old logs

Comment: I had a file in logrotate.d that symlinked to a 664 config file... that needed changing to 644. all good now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error appears when there are log files listed in the logrotate.conf that do not exist (This could be happening because the service that is supposed to generate the log is not running). Either delete the entries or remove the packages that are associated with them.